# Mimic Photoshop RGB levels with CSS and SVG filter

Tags: html, css, svg, photoshop, svg-filters

I've done this in the past and I know it exists, but for some reason I don't find it right now (wasted couple of hours with no success).

I want to mimic the `Photoshop` `RGB` levels via `CSS`.

On the following image I changed the middle value from 1 to 0.5.

[image]

I wanna get the same effect (or at least as close as possible) with CSS.

I've tried with the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/txwu3so5/

I need to find some replacement code to get that effect. The actual code affects the white color (I don't want that).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
.img_02 {
    filter: url(#level-50); 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="position:absolute;height:0;">
    <defs>
        <filter id="level-50" x="0" y="0">
            <!-- begin of code to replace -->
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="
                0.5 0 0 0 0
                0 0.5 0 0 0
                0 0 0.5 0 0
                0 0   0 1 0"
            />
            <!-- end of code to replace -->
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>

<img class="img_01" src="https://image.ibb.co/kzz41Q/image.png" />
<br /><br />
<img class="img_02" src="https://image.ibb.co/kzz41Q/image.png" />

</body>

</html>
```

In `Photoshop` I usually change from 1 to different values, for example: 0.75, 0.5, etc. I want to mimic this somehow with `CSS`. I remembered I used a code very similar to the above one, the only thing that needs to be changed is the replacement code.

**[EDIT 1]**

This is part of another problem. It is a requirement to use the `SVG` `filter` tag.

Comment: `hue-rotate(90deg)` is a valid CSS value for the `filter` property. You don't need an SVG for that.

Comment: anyway I don't need hue rotation. What I need is something like bright level change (not exactly like that but something similar) but that modification cannot affect the white and black, in the same way Photoshop levels does.

Comment: Ah I see. You'll probably need to calculate a colour matrix... Oof, that's not gonna be fun XD

Comment: I think in the past I used a simpler solution than a color matrix but that would work for me too.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically updating the gamma of the image here.  There is a built-in filter component in SVG to do that.

```
<feComponentTransfer type="gamma" ...>
```

See demo below.

*Note: the filter doesn't update properly on Chrome, so try this demo with Firefox instead*

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var gamma = document.getElementById("gamma");
var gammaR = document.getElementById("gammaR");
var gammaG = document.getElementById("gammaG");
var gammaB = document.getElementById("gammaB");

slider.addEventListener("input", function(evt) {

  var sliderValue = evt.target.value;
  gamma.textContent = sliderValue;
  gammaR.setAttribute("exponent", sliderValue);
  gammaG.setAttribute("exponent", sliderValue);
  gammaB.setAttribute("exponent", sliderValue);

});
```

```css
.img_02 {
    filter: url(#level-50); 
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="position:absolute;height:0;">
    <defs>
        <filter id="level-50" x="0" y="0">
            <!-- begin of code to replace -->
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncR type="gamma" exponent="2.2" id="gammaR"/>
                <feFuncG type="gamma" exponent="2.2" id="gammaG"/>
                <feFuncB type="gamma" exponent="2.2" id="gammaB"/>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <!-- end of code to replace -->
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>

<img class="img_01" src="https://image.ibb.co/kzz41Q/image.png" />
<img class="img_02" src="https://image.ibb.co/kzz41Q/image.png" />

<br/>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="4" step="0.1" value="1"/>
<p id="gamma"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To fully duplicate the RGB levels capability from Photoshop, you'd need three filter components: an feComponentTransfer/gamma and two feComponentTransfer/tables. If you're just adjusting the middle pivot value as above, you just need the first feComponentTranfer. To read more on how ComponentTransfers work - please see the [webplatform docs](http://www.webplatform.org/docs/svg/elements/feComponentTransfer/) (although they've started to rot a little.

```
<filter id="RGBlevels" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">

 <!-- set the value of the exponent to 1/[middle pivot input value] you'd use in Photoshop -->

  <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncR type="gamma" exponent="2"/>
      <feFuncG type="gamma" exponent="2"/>
      <feFuncB type="gamma" exponent="2"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>

 <!-- this primitive changes the start and end input values by specifying a new color curve. The values below, for example, set the start value to rgb(76.5,76.5,76.5) and the end value to rgb(204,204,204) -->

  <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 0 0 0 .2 .4 .6 .8 1 1 1"/>
      <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0 0 0 .2 .4 .6 .8 1 1 1"/>
      <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 0 0 0 .2 .4 .6 .8 1 1 1"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>

 <!-- this primitive changes the output values to rgb(25.5,25.5, 25.5) <-> rgb(229.5,229.5,229.5) -->
  <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncR type="table" tableValues=".1 .9"/>
      <feFuncG type="table" tableValues=".1 .9"/>
      <feFuncB type="table" tableValues=".1 .9"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

Comment: I tested this for a while, the second feComponentTransfer filter should come before gamma adjustment to match the result produced by Photoshop