# How to apply Photoshop-style color curves filters to an HTML tag?

Tags: html, css, colors, curve, svg-filters

I'm trying to replicate the following Photoshop color curves filter in an HTML `video` tag.

[image: Photoshop color curves tool]

The closest answer I've found so far is how to add [Photoshop-like color levels with CSS and SVG Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284984/mimic-photoshop-rgb-levels-with-css-and-svg-filter) but it's not quite what I need.

Any approach using CSS, SVG Filters, or even a third-party library is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

feComponentTransfer / table is how you implement color curves. This filter will - roughly - produce that curve combo and should give you a place to start. The first feComponentTransfer implements the color curves (I eyeballed the values - you'll want to go back and do it more carefully). The second implements the white-point adjustment.

I *think* the order is correct, but I'm not a Photoshop expert, so you may have to put the white point adjustment first.

```
<filter id="color-curve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.0 0.22 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.8 0.86 0.92 0.96 0.98 1.0"/>
  <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.0 0.0 0.05 0.1 0.22 0.4 0.6 0.83 0.92 0.97 1.0"/>
  <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.1 0.8"/>
</feComponentTransfer>

<feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.1 1"/>
  <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.1 1"/>
  <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.1 1"/>
</feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

I wrote the docs for webplatform on feComponentTransfer linked here: http://www.webplatform.org/docs/svg/elements/feComponentTransfer/

There is no more comprehensive guide to how this filter primitive works so just read that carefully.